# Probleme with mongoose - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I come to you because I have a problem that I can not solve. 
I use nodejs, express and mongodb especially mongoose.

My express server works, but i can't insert documents into my database and i don't know why. With "console.log()" i saw that mongoose.model.save is never called or there is a probleme with this function.

My app.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var connect = require('connect');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Configuration
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.json());  
app.use(connect.urlencoded());

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 


app.listen(port);

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);

console.log('The App runs on port ' + port);
```

My route.js

```
var writeData = require('/config/writeData');

var baseurl = '/niceproject'

module.exports = function(app) {



app.get(baseurl + '/', function(req, res) {

    res.end("Node-Android-Project"); 
});




app.post(baseurl + '/writeTemp', function(req, res) {

    var heure = req.body.heure;
    var temperature = req.body.temperature;

    console.log('req.body' + req.body);

    writeData.writeTemperature(heure,temperature,function(found){
        console.log(found);
        res.json(found);
    });
});
}
```

My writeData.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var model = require('/config/models.js');
var temperatureCollection = model.temperature;
var personneCollection = model.personne ; 
var sonCollection = model.sound;

exports.writeTemperature = function(heure,temperature,callback) {


var newTemperature = new temperatureCollection({
    id : 1,
    heure: new Date(),
    temperature : temperature
});


console.log('new temp: ' + newTemperature);
newTemperature.save(function(err){
    console.log('test');
    if(err){
        console.log('erreur' +  err);
        callback(err);
    }
    console.log(newTemperature);
    callback({'response':"temperature ajouté"});
});


}
```

and my model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var temperatureSchema = mongoose.Schema({    
    id : Number,
    temperature : Number,
    heure : Date
});

var personneSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id : Number,
    nbPersonne : Number,
    heure : Date
});

var sonSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id : Number,
    niveauDb : Number,
    heure : Date
});


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nightAdvisorDatabase');


var temperatureModel = mongoose.model('temperature', temperatureSchema);   
var personneModel = mongoose.model('personne', personneSchema);
var soundModel = mongoose.model('niveauDb',sonSchema);


module.exports = {
temperature : temperatureModel,
personne : personneModel,
sound : soundModel
};
```

So, when i made a post request with /niceproject/writeTemp path, i can see the newTemperatureobject in my writeData with the current date and the temperature send by the request, but i have problems with the newTemperature.save, nothings happens

Thanks for reading me 
Hope than you could help me and sorry for my approximate english

Comment: Did you get any error?!

Comment: You should add some error checking for the Mongoose connection, to see whether you actually are connected or not. See [here](http://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/). What you need are the lines with `mongoose.connection.on(...`. See that you actually get connected when the app starts.

Comment: I added mongoose.connection.on('connected') ('error) and ('disconnected') but nothings appens too. But when i try sudo service mongod status i have :  Active: active (running)  
if i run mongoShell and try to show dbs, i don't have the one that  should have been created

Answer (score 0):

If i read you right, the save method is not working on your model.

when you call the .save(), you should pass two parameters to the callback on the save method .
Instead of this one below.

```
newTemperature.save(function(err){
console.log('test');
if(err){
    console.log('erreur' +  err);
    callback(err);
}
console.log(newTemperature);
callback({'response':"temperature ajouté"});
```

});

you should write it like this.

```
newTemperature.save(function(err,newTemp){
console.log('test');
if(err){
    console.log('erreur' +  err);
    callback(err);
    return;

}
console.log(newTemp);
callback({'response':"temperature ajouté"});
```

});

The newTemp parameter is used to hold the result,should the operation be successful. 
Try out this solution. and give feedback.

It appears your are not using Promises or async/await to handle the asynchronous operations. please do look into anyone of them (especially async/await) available in node >= v7.7. It will make working with async operations a pleasure, shorter code with no callback hell.

Cheers.

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work. I'm going to take a look to async/await